# Moderation when variables X and Y correlate

Tags: regression, correlation, interaction, causality

My study is not intervention-based, and both the X and Y variables were collected at the same time point. As such, the data only allows for correlation analysis and does not establish a causal relationship between X and Y. I am wondering if it is still appropriate to analize the moderating role of W on the relationship between X and Y.

Comment: Sure you can. You might not be able to tell from the data alone which way causality goes, but one of the whole points of the New Causal Revolution is that it is sometimes possible to get causal information from observational data.

Comment: @Noah I have updated the title

Comment: @AdrianKeister thanks for the response

Comment: what do you mean by moderating role of W ? what is W? why do you perceive correlation does not help us analyse  the causal relation ?

Comment: correlation coefficient  could be spurious on account of a specific moderator variable affecting the X and Y concurrently. It is not bad to test a logical moderating factor for its role